# PyInstaller FileNotFoundError when running program

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, llama-index

I'm encountering an issue while trying to create a standalone executable from my Python program using PyInstaller. After building the executable and attempting to run it, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
   File "llama_index\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI277362\\llama_index\\VERSION'
[27800] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

The error occurs in my main.py file at line 16, which contains the following code:

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

import openai
from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader, LLMPredictor, ServiceContext
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
```

It seems that there is an issue with accessing the 'llama_index' directory within the temporary folder created by PyInstaller (_MEI277362). When I checked the temporary folder, the 'llama_index' directory was missing, which led me to believe that there might be an error in the packaging process.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!